# Nestjs Excel Upload: error connecting to server

Tags: nestjs

I have an excel of 5000 records, when I try to upload it via postman it throws the below message:

```
"Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:3000/data/import."
```

But when I do the same process with 500 records it works.

Code for reference:

```
@Post('import')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
        return await this.service.testImport(file);
    }
```

testImport is a service which does the required formatting and saving the data.

Comment: NestJS relies on `multer` for file uploads. Did you have a look at the default configuration of multer? If my memory is correct, there are settings to setup the max filesize.

Comment: where do I look for this configuration? And the file isn't more than 1Mb, or is this related to my plugin used to read records from excel.
Plugin used: read-excel-file from npm

Comment: You can add the configs in main.ts. Configs are 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));